# TIM6 , basic time generation function not working

Tags: c++, timer, arm, embedded, stm32

I am trying to use TIM6 on STM32F103C8T6 to generate time and blink an led but the timer doesnt see to be working, what other parameters do i need to initialize in order to be able to use the timer ?  code below ?

```
#include "stm32f10x.h"

int main(void)
{
RCC->APB1ENR |= 0x00000010 ; // CLOCK SIGNAL TO BASIC TIMER 6 IS INITIALIZED

RCC->APB2ENR |= 0x00000004 ; //CLOCK SIGNAL TO GPIO PORT A IS INITIALIZED

GPIOA->CRL |= 0x33333333 ; // LOWER PINS OF GPIO PORT A ARE DEFINED AS PUSH AND PULL OUTPUT

TIM6->CR1 |= 0x0081 ; // COUNTER AND AUTO RELOAD BUFFER ENABLED

TIM6->PSC |= 0x1F40 ; // PRESCALER SET AS 8000

TIM6->ARR |= 0x05DC ; // AUTO RELOAD REGISTER SET AT 1000

while(1)
{
    if ( TIM6->CNT == 1000 )
    {
        GPIOA->BSRR |= 0X0044 ; //SET PINS 2 AND 6 OF GPIOA TO HIGH
    }

    if ( TIM6->CNT == 0x05DC )
    {
        GPIOA->BRR |= 0X0044 ; //SET PINS 2 AND 6 OF GPIOA TO HIGH
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Testing for equality with the timer value is a bad idea. Use a `>=` comparison. Unless the timer is running very slowly, the chances of doing the comparison when the timer is on an exact value is low.

Comment: i just corrected that but it still doesnt work .....

Comment: Can you see the timer's registers in a debugger, breakpoint and see if the timer is counting up. That will tell you if it's initialised correctly.

Comment: i still dont understand ho wto use the debugger well. But i suspect the problem is with the code some where

Comment: Are you sure that STM32F103C8T6 even has a TIM6?  Section 17 of this [datasheet](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/59/b9/ba/7f/11/af/43/d5/CD00171190.pdf/files/CD00171190.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00171190.pdf) suggests that it may not have TIM6.

Comment: @Colin__s: What if the timer overflows? Both approaches are bad actually; correct would be to use a Timer with Output capability and let the hardware do the job. At least use the compare-interrupt to change to output, that's what it is for.

Comment: Thanks guys, using timer 2 worked. I was just working using the stm32f10x manual didnt bother to look at my device.

Answer (score 3):

STM32F103C8T6 has only TIM1 - TIM4, so trying to use TIM6 is doomed to fail. See "Table 4. Timer feature comparison" in [the datasheet](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/33/d4/6f/1d/df/0b/4c/6d/CD00161566.pdf/files/CD00161566.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00161566.pdf) (page 17).